# Grammar interpretation of 来た人をごはんにして食べるんだ

Tags: grammar

The sentence 来た人をごはんにして食べるんだ comes from [this source](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-lessons/4-8-the-restaurant-that-has-many-orders/) as N4 reading. However, I find some higher-level grammars appear in these N4 lessons so I have a confusion here.

1. Is にして here [にして of N1 grammar](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6-ni-shite/) or [にする of N5 grammar](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-ni-suru-meaning/)?
2. Does を support して or 食べる?
3. What is the literal translation of the sentence?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. This is a part of the `A + を + B + にする` construction, which means "to make A B", "to turn A into B", etc. (B can be either a noun or a na-adjective).

   > - 死者をゾンビにする to turn the dead into zombies
   > - 火曜日を休みにする to make Tuesday a day off
   > - 部屋をきれいにする to make the room clean
2. 来た人を attaches to して (because it's part of the AをBにする construction), but 来た人 ("a person who came") is the object of both する and 食べる, anyway. See the translation below.
3. "It's that [the chef] turns a person who came in (to this restaurant) into a meal and eats [him]."

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind explanation!